# Apache Tiles 3 render Struts 2 action

Tags: java, struts2, tiles, tiles-3

Is it possible in Tiles 3 to render a result of action execution? 
Something like the following:

```
<definition name="body" template="/WEB-INF/layout.jsp" preparer="com.my.MyPreparer">
    <put-list-attribute name="list0">
        <add-attribute value="/portlet/Login.do"/>
        <add-attribute value="/portlet/Logout.do"/>
        <add-attribute value="/portlet/Home.do"/>
    </put-list-attribute>
</definition>
```

Comment: I'm confused, are you using the struts2-tiles3-plugin? Because yes you can use tiles to render the view for actions... generally a preparer is not needed as the action should be able to do most of the preparing...

Comment: It can work if you change extension to `.jsp`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Looks like a XY problem.